# Reducing memory allocation of a generator in Julia

Tags: iterator, julia, generator

I am trying to reduce the memory allocation of an inner loop in my code. Below the part that is not working as expected.

```
using Random 
using StatsBase
using BenchmarkTools
using Distributions

a_dist = Distributions.DiscreteUniform(1, 99)
v_dist = Distributions.DiscreteUniform(1, 2)
population_size = 10000
population = [rand(a_dist, population_size) rand(v_dist, population_size)]


find_all_it3(f::Function, A) = (p[2] for p in eachrow(A) if f(p[1]))

@btime begin 
    c_pool = find_all_it3(x -> (x < 5), population)
    c_pool_dict = countmap(c_pool, alg=:dict)
end


@btime begin
    c_pool_indexes = findall(x -> (x < 5) ,  view(population, :, 1))
    c_pool_dict = countmap(population[c_pool_indexes, 2], alg=:dict)
end
```

I was hoping that the generator (find_all_it3) would not need to allocate much memory.
however as per the `btime` output it seems that there is an allocation for each loop.

```
  98.040 μs (10006 allocations: 625.64 KiB)
  18.894 μs (18 allocations: 11.95 KiB)
```

Now in my scenario the speed and allocation of the `findall` eventually become an issue, hence I was trying to find a better alternative through generator/iterators so that less allocation occur; is there a way to do that? Are there options to consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an explaination for it but here are the results of a few tests I made

- The best time is achieved with `view(population, :, 1) .< 5` (`test4`)
- using `broadcast!` reduces allocations a bit (`test5`)
- the best way to reduce allocation is to do your own loop (`test6`)

```
using BenchmarkTools
using StatsBase

population_size = 10000
population = [rand(1:99, population_size) rand(1:2, population_size)]

find_all_it(f::Function, A) = (p[2] for p in eachrow(A) if f(p[1]))

function test1(population)
    c_pool = find_all_it(x -> x < 5, population)
    c_pool_dict = countmap(c_pool, alg=:dict)
end

function test3(population)
    c_pool_indexes = findall(x -> x < 5,  view(population, :, 1))
    c_pool_dict = countmap(view(population,c_pool_indexes, 2), alg=:dict)
end

function test4(population)
    c_pool_indexes = view(population, :, 1) .< 5
    c_pool_dict = countmap(view(population,c_pool_indexes, 2), alg=:dict)
end

function test5(c_pool_indexes, population)
    broadcast!(<, c_pool_indexes, view(population, :, 1), 5)
    c_pool_dict = countmap(view(population,c_pool_indexes, 2), alg=:dict)
end

function test6(population)
    d = Dict{Int,Int}()
    for i in eachindex(view(population, :, 1))
        if population[i, 1] < 5
            d[population[i,2]] = 1 + get(d,population[i,2],0)
        end
    end
    return d
end

julia> @btime test1(population);
  68.200 μs (10004 allocations: 625.59 KiB)

julia> @btime test3(population);
  14.800 μs (14 allocations: 9.00 KiB)

julia> @btime test4(population);
  7.250 μs (8 allocations: 9.33 KiB)

julia> temp = zeros(Bool, population_size);

julia> @btime test5(temp, population);
  16.599 μs (5 allocations: 3.78 KiB)

julia> @btime test6(population);
  11.299 μs (4 allocations: 608 bytes)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the effort you put in researching the question, it is helpful and appreciated. I will let the question open for a little while. I am also doing some further study as well.

Comment: About the fifth test, I think that the reduced allocation is because the ´c_pool_indexes´ is initialised outside of the function.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in assigning the answer. The issue I face was once I put the method into the larger program, then the results weren't the same anymore (the fastest: t4 was now slower than t3), and in the end it happened that t6 was the fastest (although the reduction in memory wasn't that drastic). This is annoying in the sense that I would need to find an alternative to reproduce issues..